# Where did he go?

Tags: riddle, humor

"You are here to report a missing person sir?"

"Yes. My brother"

"I am sorry. Can you describe him? Photo?"

"He is my identical twin brother"

"Oh well. That's good. Any distingushing marks?"

"We both have this birthmark right here"

"Looks like-hmmm- a wing or something?"

"That is what they all say"

"How and when did he disappear?"

"We were caught in the storms. Two storms actually. We both and many like us were going for a fun swim on a vessel and the first storm hit. Lot of rain and floods. We were tossed around and felt like we were sinking.We were drenched.Then slowly the water stopped. We felt safe for a while"

"For a while?"

"Well then the second storm hit. It was so windy. Felt like a tornado. We were tossed around. Went on for an hour! Then it stopped all of a sudden. I looked for my brother everywhere. He was nowhere to be found. Please help me"

"Hmm. I am sorry sir. I do not want to raise your hopes. We get these missing person reports all the time but we have not been able to solve a single case!"

"What?"

"Yes. It is like they all disappear into the thin air!"

Who am I? What happened to my brother and where exactly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You and your brother are both:

> **SOCKS** from a pair! (Hence why you look alike and both have a 'birthmark... like a wing', possibly a logo on one side or a patch of colour on the heel...)

And (of course!) your brother has somehow been:

> **lost in the wash!** Note the description of the rainstorm - as the water entered the washing machine and drenched both socks and the rest of the dirty washing ('many like us'), tossed about as the drum rotated - and then the tornado, i.e. the tumble dryer!

I fear, sadly, that your brother may never be found (as so often, as you say, with 'these missing person reports all the time...'). But hopefully those who you seek to serve won't judge you too harshly if your behaviour becomes a little *odd* from now on!

Comment: Jnfure naq Qelre. V ybfr zbfg fbpxf va gur Qelre. Nyfb gur Jvat funcrq znex vf n oenaq ybtb

Comment: That tornado lasts an hour?

Comment: @FlorianF Well hurricanes can last for several days or mere minutes, so it's not unrealistic.